# Quasi-symmetric functions and determinants

Tags: determinants, symmetric-functions

In the field of *symmetric functions*, determinants show up all the time. For example, Jacobi-Trudi, Giambelli identity, definition of Schur polynomials as a quotient of determinants, and so on. This phenomenon extends to the *non-commutative* setting.

However, I have not seen much of determinant formulas when studying *quasi-symmetric* functions. For example, there is no analogue of the Jacobi-Trudi identities that I know of.

**Q: Why are determinants not present?**

One explanation is that the presence of determinants is related to the interpretation of lattice paths, so QSYM simply lacks this connection, perhaps. Also, as a determinant is a sum over permutations, it seem reasonable that the output is related to the introduction of *symmetry* and not quasi-symmetry.

**Q: Is there another construction that replaces determinants?**

In some areas, pfaffians (or maybe immanants) replace the determinants. One should therefore look for something else entirely for QSYM.
Sum over shuffles with a sign?

Comment: This is a really soft question, so I'm not sure what constitutes an answer. But I'm wondering if the Hamel-Goulden formulas for skew Schur functions have some generalization to P-partitions.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ah, there was a paper today on arxiv where a Murnaghan-Nakayama-type rule is proved for P-partitions. http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1903.00551

Comment: You mean Corollary 6.17?

Comment: Well, Thm 6.9 is for general P-partitions, and the skew Schur ones is a special case.

Comment: Ah! Now that you're telling me, I see in what sense this is a Murnaghan-Nakayama rule...